# What library determines how SOAP messages are serialised?

Tags: java, xml, soap, jaxb

I am working on a JAVA (Spring3) MW project that makes calls to other backend web services. However, some SOAP messages are '''malformed''' (I think) and I cannot trace where the problem lies.

I am not quite sure what details I should include, but here is some that might be handy: It is a JAVA6 project, using Spring3, and is deployed on Tomcat 8 for testing purposes.

Here is a SOAP example that resembles the message my code is generating:

```
<S:Envelope 
    xmlns:S="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/">
 <S:Body xmlns="http://backend.company.com/">
   <GetCustomerInfo>
      <MsgHeader>
         <SomeTag>some value</SomeTag>
      </MsgHeader> 
      <Body>
         <CustomerId>123456</CustomerId>
      </Body> 
  </GetCustomerInfo>
</S:Body>
</S:Envelope>
```

When I send this SOAP message to the backend web service, I receive the following error:

`Exception: : Element must have a namespace specified if there is a default namespace in scope : Body`

When I change my message as follows, everything magically starts working. The only difference is where I define the namespace for my Soap body element.

```
<S:Envelope 
    xmlns:S="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/>
 <S:Body>
   <GetCustomerInfo xmlns="http://backend.company.com/">
      <MsgHeader>
         <SomeTag>some value</SomeTag>
      </MsgHeader> 
      <Body>
         <CustomerId>123456</CustomerId>
      </Body> 
  </GetCustomerInfo>
</S:Body>
</S:Envelope>
```

I have 11 questions:

(1) Is there anything wrong with my initial message related to XML-conformance? They both look very similar to me.

(10) What library in my code converts my JAVA object to the XML message? And what changes do I need in my configuration to produce SOAP messages that are like the latter example?

(11) In my fist XML file, what would be the "expanded name" for my first Body tag? would it be `http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/:Body` or `http://backend.company.com/:Body`?

In case it is relevant, the service class my code calls is annotated with the following tags:

```
@WebService(
    targetNamespace = "http://backend.company.com/",
    name = "MyServiceName"
)
@XmlSeeAlso({ObjectFactory.class})
@SOAPBinding(
    parameterStyle = ParameterStyle.BARE
)
```

Comment: 1st XML is indeed wrong as body is from soap ns. So 2nd XML is correct and your WS server shall be generating correct soap message

Comment: @Namphibian: Actiually no... the ```backend.company.com``` namespace in both snippets define the default namespace only and this should apply to all child elements that do not have an explicit namespace prefix. So, in both cases, my custom ```backend.company.com``` namespace only applies to the child elements and not to the ```<S:Body>``` element (as it already has a given explicit namespace)

Comment: Okay then. I prefer top down so might be missing something.

Answer (score 0):

OK. finally figured out the answer to my question. The web app passes down the JAVA object to the JDK runtime libraries for unmarshalling. And the JDK uses the JAX-WS RI of the JDK runtime to actually build the SOAP message.

Apparently the problem is caused by a mismatch of the JDK versions between the client and the server.

Initially I had started Tomcat using JDK1.8 and by default JDK 1.8 uses JAX-WS RI 2.2.9 for marshalling/unmarshalling.

The server on the other hand was using JDK1.7, which uses JAX-WS RI 2.2.4 for marshalling/unmarshalling of the SOAP messages.

When i switched to JDK1.7, all my problems were solved.

Note that, this has nothing to do with the JDK that was us used to comppile the source code, but is related to the runtime JDK version that is used to run the code.

BTW, both messages are valid and functionally equivalent XML messages. It is just that earlier versions do not agree.